# Unable to use "Web deploy" on Windows Server 2012 HTTP ERROR 404.7

Tags: windows-server-2012, iis-8, deployment

I am using Windows server 2012 and Web Deploy 3.5.
When I try to publish from Visual Studio I get 404 and suggests to follow the following link

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE

Both wmsrv and remote agent and running and properly configured.
After checking wmsrv logs see the same error over and over again:

2013-11-27 18:11:41 10.7.140.235 HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=DevStatsDashboard 8172 - 10.7.141.48 - - 404 7 0 1388

From support site http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891 this means HTTP ERROR 404.7 – FILE_EXTENSION_DENIED

However I am using IIS8 and I am allowing .axd files

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, the problem was I trusted Web Platform...

Installing defaults settings for Web Deploy 3.5 didn't install all required components like:

[image]

You need to install "IIS Deployment Handler" to be able to use it.

Comment: Mine was installed already but a Repair did the trick

Comment: My setup screen does not include the IIS Deployment Handler node. I'm using v3.6. Do you know why this is missing?